# how fix PUT , error 500 id = undefined ReactJs NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

error 500 , id = undefined, no idea why , 
I try to post whatever you may need

how can I fix this issue?

thats is function

```
 handleSubmit = (e, id) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const userIdData = { id };
 const config = {
 method: "PUT",
 headers: {
 "Content-Type": "application/json",
 },
  body: JSON.stringify({userIdData, livree: new Date().toISOString().slice(11, 16)}),
 };
   const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls";
   fetch(url, config)
   .then(res => res.json())
     .then(res => {
     if (res.error) {
      alert(res.error);
       else {
        alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
        }
        }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
        }).finally(() => this.setState({ redirect: true })); }
```

my routes

```
 app.put('/api/alluserpls', (req, res, ) => {
 const formData = req.body;
 const userId = req.body.id;
 const deleteQuery = `UPDATE alluserpls SET ? WHERE id = ${userId}`;
 connection.query(deleteQuery, err => {
 if (err) {
 console.log(err)
 res.status(500).send("Erreur lors de la modification des users");
 } else {
 res.sendStatus(200);
 }
 });
 });
```

my button

```
     <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e, datass.id)}>
     <button type="submit">PUT</button>
     </form>
```

console.log result

```
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
  your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE id = undefined' at 
  line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'UPDATE alluserpls SET ? WHERE id = undefined'
   }
  PUT /api/alluserpls 500 14.354 ms - 40
```

Comment: it could be inside `req.body.userIdData` or might be even itself. 
`console.log(req.body)` first line at your route handler and debug the content in it at ur terminal/server logs.

Comment: @SultanH. the result on console?log { userIdData: { id: 156 }, livree: '14:03' }

Answer (score 0):

Replace the userId line with this:

```
 const userId = req.body.userIdData.id;
```

with ES6 Object Destructring:

```
const { id } = req.body.userIdData
```

Also, it'll be cleaner if you remove the `formData` declaration since it's not used in the route handler.

Comment: new error ,   code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE id = 157' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'UPDATE alluserpls SET ? WHERE id = 157'
}
PUT /api/alluserpls 500 16.734 ms - 40

Comment: Try replacing this `WHERE id = ${userId}` with that `WHERE id = "${userId}"` , Wrapping the user id with double-quotation marks.

Comment: error ,code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE id = "157"' at line 1`,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'UPDATE alluserpls SET ? WHERE id = "157"'
}
PUT /api/alluserpls 500 15.212 ms - 40

Comment: hello any idea pls ?

Comment: I believe you have to write the SQL update command in this syntax `UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2 WHERE id=100;`, instead of having the `?` after `SET`.